# Bootstrap collapse button not working on smartphone

Tags: android, html, ios, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to display a `div` using the bootstrap collapse class. It works smoothly, but when I try to use the button on an iPhone, iPad or any other 'smart device', the `div` is not displayed.

Here is my code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary facts-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#watch-facts">    Lees meer </button>

<div id="watch-facts" class="collapse out extras-facts">
    <ul>
        <li>One.</li>
        <li>Two and two again</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

When i disable this .js script, it seems to work on a mobile phone. Don't know where the problem is.

```
!function($){

$.support.transition = (function(){
var thisBody = document.body || document.documentElement, 
thisStyle = thisBody.style,
support = thisStyle.transition !== undefined || thisStyle.WebkitTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.MozTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.MsTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.OTransition !== undefined;
return support;
})();

var defaults = {
sectionContainer: "section",
easing: "ease",
animationTime: 1000,
pagination: true,
updateURL: false,
keyboard: true,
beforeMove: null,
afterMove: null,
loop: false
};

$.fn.swipeEvents = function() {
return this.each(function() {

    var startX,
        startY,
        $this = $(this);

    $this.bind('touchstart', touchstart);

    function touchstart(event) {
      var touches = event.originalEvent.touches;
      if (touches && touches.length) {
        startX = touches[0].pageX;
        startY = touches[0].pageY;
        $this.bind('touchmove', touchmove);
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    function touchmove(event) {
      var touches = event.originalEvent.touches;
      if (touches && touches.length) {
        var deltaX = startX - touches[0].pageX;
        var deltaY = startY - touches[0].pageY;

        if (deltaX >= 50) {
          $this.trigger("swipeLeft");
        }
        if (deltaX <= -50) {
          $this.trigger("swipeRight");
        }
        if (deltaY >= 50) {
          $this.trigger("swipeUp");
        }
        if (deltaY <= -50) {
          $this.trigger("swipeDown");
        }
        if (Math.abs(deltaX) >= 50 || Math.abs(deltaY) >= 50) {
          $this.unbind('touchmove', touchmove);
        }
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    }

  });
};
$.fn.onepage_scroll = function(options){
var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options),
el = $(this),
sections = $(settings.sectionContainer)
total = sections.length,
status = "off",
topPos = 0,
lastAnimation = 0,
quietPeriod = 500,
paginationList = "";

$.fn.transformPage = function(settings, pos, index) {
 if ( ! $.support.transition ) {
    $(this).animate({
     'top': pos + '%'
    },400);
    return;
 }  
  $(this).css({
    "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(0, " + pos + "%, 0)",
    "-webkit-transition": "all " + settings.animationTime + "ms " + settings.easing,
    "-moz-transform": "translate3d(0, " + pos + "%, 0)",
    "-moz-transition": "all " + settings.animationTime + "ms " + settings.easing,
    "-ms-transform": "translate3d(0, " + pos + "%, 0)",
    "-ms-transition": "all " + settings.animationTime + "ms " + settings.easing,
    "transform": "translate3d(0, " + pos + "%, 0)",
    "transition": "all " + settings.animationTime + "ms " + settings.easing
  });
  $(this).one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
    if (typeof settings.afterMove == 'function') settings.afterMove(index);
  });
}

$.fn.jumpTo = function(newIndex) {
  var el = $(this)
  index = $(settings.sectionContainer +".active").data("index");
  current = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + index + "']");
  next = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + (newIndex+1) + "']");
  if(next.length < 1) {
    if (settings.loop == true) {
      pos = 0;
      next = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + (newIndex) + "']");
    } else {
      return
    }

  }else {
    pos = (newIndex * 100) * -1;
  }

  current.removeClass("active")
  next.addClass("active");
  if(settings.pagination == true) {
    $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + index + "']").removeClass("active");
    $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + next.data("index") + "']").addClass("active");
  }

  $("body")[0].className = $("body")[0].className.replace(/\bviewing-page-\d.*?\b/g, '');
  $("body").addClass("viewing-page-"+next.data("index"))

  if (history.replaceState && settings.updateURL == true) {
    var href = window.location.href.substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf('#')) + "#" + (index + 1);
    history.pushState( {}, document.title, href );
  }
  el.transformPage(settings, pos, newIndex);
}




$.fn.moveDown = function() {
  var el = $(this)
  index = $(settings.sectionContainer +".active").data("index");
  current = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + index + "']");
  next = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + (index + 1) + "']");
  if(next.length < 1) {
    if (settings.loop == true) {
      pos = 0;
      next = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='1']");
    } else {
      return
    }

  }else {
    pos = (index * 100) * -1;
  }
  if (typeof settings.beforeMove == 'function') settings.beforeMove( current.data("index"));
  current.removeClass("active")
  next.addClass("active");
  if(settings.pagination == true) {
    $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + index + "']").removeClass("active");
    $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + next.data("index") + "']").addClass("active");
  }

  $("body")[0].className = $("body")[0].className.replace(/\bviewing-page-\d.*?\b/g, '');
  $("body").addClass("viewing-page-"+next.data("index"))

  if (history.replaceState && settings.updateURL == true) {
    var href = window.location.href.substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf('#')) + "#" + (index + 1);
    history.pushState( {}, document.title, href );
  }
  el.transformPage(settings, pos, index);
}

$.fn.moveUp = function() {
  var el = $(this)
  index = $(settings.sectionContainer +".active").data("index");
  current = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + index + "']");
  next = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + (index - 1) + "']");

  if(next.length < 1) {
    if (settings.loop == true) {
      pos = ((total - 1) * 100) * -1;
      next = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='"+total+"']");
    }
    else {
      return
    }
  }else {
    pos = ((next.data("index") - 1) * 100) * -1;
  }
  if (typeof settings.beforeMove == 'function') settings.beforeMove(current.data("index"));
  current.removeClass("active")
  next.addClass("active")
  if(settings.pagination == true) {
    $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + index + "']").removeClass("active");
    $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + next.data("index") + "']").addClass("active");
  }
  $("body")[0].className = $("body")[0].className.replace(/\bviewing-page-\d.*?\b/g, '');
  $("body").addClass("viewing-page-"+next.data("index"))

  if (history.replaceState && settings.updateURL == true) {
    var href = window.location.href.substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf('#')) + "#" + (index - 1);
    history.pushState( {}, document.title, href );
  }
  el.transformPage(settings, pos, index);
}

function init_scroll(event, delta) {
    deltaOfInterest = delta;
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    // Cancel scroll if currently animating or within quiet period
    if(timeNow - lastAnimation < quietPeriod + settings.animationTime) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    if (deltaOfInterest < 0) {
      el.moveDown()
    } else {
      el.moveUp()
    }
    lastAnimation = timeNow;
}

// Prepare everything before binding wheel scroll

el.addClass("onepage-wrapper").css("position","relative");
$.each( sections, function(i) {
  $(this).css({
    position: "absolute",
    top: topPos + "%"
  }).addClass("section").attr("data-index", i+1);
  topPos = topPos + 100;
  if(settings.pagination == true) {
    paginationList += "<li><a data-index='"+(i+1)+"' href='#" + (i+1) + "'></a></li>"
  }
});

el.swipeEvents().bind("swipeDown", function(){
  el.moveUp();
}).bind("swipeUp", function(){
  el.moveDown();
});

// Create Pagination and Display Them
if(settings.pagination == true) {
  $("<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right onepage-pagination'>" + paginationList + "</ul>").prependTo(".navbar-collapse");
  posTop = (el.find(".onepage-pagination").height() / 2) * -1;
  el.find(".onepage-pagination").css("margin-top", posTop);
}

if(window.location.hash != "" && window.location.hash != "#1") {
  init_index = window.location.hash.replace("#", "")
  $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + init_index + "']").addClass("active")
  $("body").addClass("viewing-page-"+ init_index)
  if(settings.pagination == true) $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + init_index + "']").addClass("active");

  next = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + (init_index) + "']");
  if(next) {
    next.addClass("active")
    if(settings.pagination == true) $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + (init_index) + "']").addClass("active");
    $("body")[0].className = $("body")[0].className.replace(/\bviewing-page-\d.*?\b/g, '');
    $("body").addClass("viewing-page-"+next.data("index"))
    if (history.replaceState && settings.updateURL == true) {
      var href = window.location.href.substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf('#')) + "#" + (init_index);
      history.pushState( {}, document.title, href );
    }
  }
  pos = ((init_index - 1) * 100) * -1;
  el.transformPage(settings, pos, init_index);

}else{
  $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='1']").addClass("active")
  $("body").addClass("viewing-page-1")
  if(settings.pagination == true) $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='1']").addClass("active");
}
if(settings.pagination == true) {
  $(".onepage-pagination li a").click(function (){
    var page_index = $(this).data("index");
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
      current = $(settings.sectionContainer + ".active")
      next = $(settings.sectionContainer + "[data-index='" + (page_index) + "']");
      if(next) {
        current.removeClass("active")
        next.addClass("active")
        $(".onepage-pagination li a" + ".active").removeClass("active");
        $(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + (page_index) + "']").addClass("active");
        $("body")[0].className = $("body")[0].className.replace(/\bviewing-page-\d.*?\b/g, '');
        $("body").addClass("viewing-page-"+next.data("index"))
      }
      pos = ((page_index - 1) * 100) * -1;
      el.transformPage(settings, pos, page_index);
    }
    if (settings.updateURL == false) return false;
  });
}



$(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;
  init_scroll(event, delta);
});

if(settings.keyboard == true) {
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
    switch(e.which) {
      case 38:
        if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') el.moveUp()
      break;
      case 40:
        if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') el.moveDown()
      break;
      default: return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
return false;
}

}(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: The code you mentioned seems to be working fine here in my android phone. Can you perhaps provide some more information.

Comment: I found out there is a bug in another .js script which makes it impossible to clicked. I added it to to the question.

Comment: Do you get any console error on your browser inspect tool when including this .js? Its Ctrl + Shift + i on Chrome.

Comment: Even including this js code I'm able to make it work on my android phone and iPad perfectly. [Here is the codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxQMZa). Can you may be replicate your error here

Comment: Does it also work on your phone on this website: ic.martijnvanoeffel/wwdc-special ?

Comment: Sorry its a broken link. Can you create a link for it. Check here how to do so - [http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Here you go: http://ic.martijnvanoeffel.nl/wwdc-special/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh finally. Now that I had your complete code. I could find the issue. :-)

I fetched all your website resources and assets locally on my machine and tested and the error seems to be due to this - `event.preventDefault();` on the .js file you mentioned (onepage-scroll.js) on `line number 54`.

**Explanation :** `event.preventDefault` method is used to prevent(not trigger) the default action of the event is called within. Because of this the default action of your touch event on any tablet or smaller device will be prevented and hence did not work on native devices.

**Answer :** Remove the `event.preventDefault();` from the `touchstart` function (line 54) and it should work just fine even in your native devices. Tested and it works fine.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thnx! This helped me out, hero of the day! Also love the explanation, really makes it clear now! :-)